# Проблема с выводом даты в label из базы данных Access, хочу вывести только дату, а выводится дата и время

Tags: c#, база-данных, ado.net

Проблема с выводом даты в label из базы данных Access, хочу вывести только дату, а выводится дата и время. Маски ввода в Access стоит "00.00.0000;0;_", а Формат поля "Краткий формат даты". Выводит почему то в label 06.06.22 00:00:00, а хочу без времени. P.S. Дата Вылета, Город Вылета, Город Прилёта в запросе sql написаны слитно если что, так что всё работает, из-за сайт пробелом разделил
Код:

```cs
OleDbCommand connString1 = new OleDbCommand();
connString1.Connection = MyConn;
connString1.CommandText = ("SELECT Дата Вылета FROM Рейсы WHERE Города Вылета = @Depcity AND Города Прилета = @arrcity");
connString1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Depcity", City3.Text);
connString1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@arrcity", City4.Text); 

OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
DataTable table = new DataTable();
adapter.SelectCommand = connString1;
adapter.Fill(table);
if (table.Rows.Count == 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Подходящих запросов нету!", "Оповещение", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
    MyConn.Close();
}
else
{
    using (OleDbDataReader reader = connString1.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read()) { Dat2.Text = Convert.ToString(reader["Дата Вылета"]); }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Данные уже загружены в `DataTable`. Не нужно повторно их считывать с помощью Reader`а.

Comment: У `OleDbDataReader` есть меод `GetDateTime`. С его помощью получаете значение именно в виде `DateTime`. А потом задаёте формат вывода: [Standard date and time format strings](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings), [Custom date and time format strings](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings). Но, как я уже сказал, лучше брать значение из `DataTable`, а потом задать ему желаемый формат.